# find oldest file from list

Tags: bash, sorting

I've a file with a list of files in different directories and want to find the oldest one.
It feels like something that should be easy with some shell scripting but I don't know how to approach this. I'm sure it's really easy in perl and other scripting languages but I'd really like to know if I've missed some obvious bash solution.

Example of the contents of the source file:

```
/home/user2/file1  
/home/user14/tmp/file3  
/home/user9/documents/file9
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14842195/how-to-get-file-creation-date-time-in-bash-debian

Comment: I suggest a combination of `find` (to list the files), `ls -lc` (to sort and display) and `xargs` as a glue.

Comment: like this `find . -type f -printf '%T+ %p\n' | sort | head -1` ?

Comment: how can I restrict the find command to the files already in my list?

Comment: What is the meaning of "oldest"? Least recent modification time? Also let us know the operating system you are using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh

while IFS= read -r file; do
    [ "${file}" -ot "${oldest=$file}" ] && oldest=${file}
done < filelist.txt

echo "the oldest file is '${oldest}'"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `stat` to find the last modification time of each file, looping over your source file:

```
oldest=5555555555
while read file; do
    modtime=$(stat -c %Y "$file")
    [[ $modtime -lt $oldest ]] && oldest=$modtime && oldestf="$file"
done < sourcefile.txt
echo "Oldest file: $oldestf"
```

This uses the `%Y` format of `stat`, which is the last modification time. You could also use `%X` for last access time, or `%Z` for last change time.

Comment: Sadly, `stat` is highly unportable so this basically only works on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Use [find()](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) to find the oldest file:

```
find /home/ -type f -printf '%T+ %p\n' | sort | head -1 | cut -d' ' -f2-
```

And with source file:

```
find $(cat /path/to/source/file) -type f -printf '%T+ %p\n' | sort | head -1 | cut -d' ' -f2-
```