# Checking when a folder was created in Bash?

Tags: bash, time, directory, creation

I know you can't for files, but is there by any chance a way to check this for folders?

Comment: FYI, the word in the Linux/Unix world is "directory", not "folder".

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to get creation time of any files in linux, since

> Each file has three distinct associated timestamps: the time of last
>   data access, the time of last data modification, and the time the file
>   status last changed.

Also you as you wrote in your question "I know you can't for files, but is there by any chance a way to check this for folders?", in linux, all files and directories are considered as files, so you have your own answer in your question.

[Source](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_08)

Comment: As discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14842195/how-to-get-file-creation-date-time-in-bash-debian)

Comment: @Shelltux well then it seems to be a duplicate question. BTW thanks.