# Check if file was created more than 10 minutes from now

Tags: linux, bash, unix

In my script i want to check if file named "Flag" was created more than 10 minutes from now, and if it was, delete it.

Got something like this:

```
ZMIENNA=`find /home/maciej/testy/ -mmin +10 -name Flag`
if [ -N $ZMIENNA ]
then
        rm /home/maciej/testy/Flag
fi
```

Thank you for replying.

Comment: Why do you use -N? This option test if the file "is modified since it was last read". Maybe you want to check if the string ZMIENNA is not empty? The is -n lowercase and add "" to protect the string ZMIENNA

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What do you get with the code you have shown? How does it work as opposed to what you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use find to delete a file, for example to delete file1 in the current folder:

```
find . -name file1 -mmin +10 -exec rm {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the manual the option `-mmin` of `find` is based on the last modification date:

> ```
>  -mmin n
>         File's data was last modified n minutes ago.
> ```

As stated by this post : [How to get file creation date/time in Bash/Debian?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14842195/how-to-get-file-creation-date-time-in-bash-debian)
the creation time is not stored as file metadata on POSIX systems.