# bash to select oldest folder in directory and write to log

Tags: bash

In the `bash` below the oldest folder in a directory is selected.  If there are `3` folders in the directory `/home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/test` and nothing is done to them (ie. no files deleted, renamed) then the `bash` correctly identifies `f1` as the oldest.  However, if something is done to the folder then the `bash` identifies `f2` as the oldest. I am not sure why or how to prevent that from happening.  Thank you :).

**folders in directory**

```
f1
f2
f3
```

**Bash**

```
# oldest folder used analysis and version log created
dir=/home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/test
{
read -r -d $'\t' time && read -r -d '' filename
} < <(find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -printf '%T+\t%P\0' | sort -z )
printf "The oldest folder is $filename, created on $time and analysis done using v1.3 by $USER at $(date "+%D %r")\n" >> /home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/test/log
echo "$filename"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea of using `find` is right, but with a little tweaking like this

```
$ IFS= read -r -d $'\0' line < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf '%T@ %p\0' \ 
    2>/dev/null | sort -z -n)

$ printf "The oldest directory: %s\n" "${line#* }"
```

Similar to the one answered [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/28947/112235).

Comment: @Chris: Happy to help!

Answer (score 2):

When you edit a folder or a file in a folder, the modification date of the folder is updated. The creation date of a folder is not saved. See this question for more information [How to get file creation date/time in Bash/Debian?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14842195/how-to-get-file-creation-date-time-in-bash-debian)