# Using find command to grab the file extensions in directory in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh, ksh

So far I have tried

```
extension=$(find /home/path-to-dir -type f -name '*.*' | sed 's/^.*\.//' | sort -u)
```

It is giving me extension right after `.` but it is failing for `text.data.json`  ( I only need json)

similar example `stack/~.hello.py` ( I only need py)

---

also I m trying to find the creation date of a file ? is it possible ?

Comment: Only one question to a question, please -- creation date should be asked separately (and the answer depends on which filesystem you're using, but _usually_ the answer is no, it's not possible -- typical UNIX filesystems only store last-modified time).

Comment: Beyond that... in general, using a string variable to store a list of things isn't a great idea -- lists should be stored in arrays. That way you can ask how many things there are in the array, refer to them by number, etc.

Comment: I'm surprised, though, that your current regex _isn't_ stripping all the way to the end. They're greedy by default, and `sed` doesn't provide a way to turn that off -- if you run `echo 'foo.bar.baz' | sed 's/^.*\.//'`, you get only `baz`, not `bar.baz`. Can you provide a [mre] that lets others see your problem?

Comment: Could use : `for i in *;do [[ -f $i ]] && echo ${i##*.};done|sort -u`

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the `sed` command, we can use [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) to get the string after the **last** `.`;

```sh
find /home/path-to-dir -type f -name '*.*' -exec bash -c 'echo ${0##*.}' {} \;
```

Small example:

```
--> ls
ahahha~bla.py  bla.bla.json  ok.py  test.json  text.data.json
-->
-->
--> find . -type f -name '*.*' -exec bash -c 'echo ${0##*.}' {} \; | sort -u
json
py
```

[Extract filename and extension in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965053/extract-filename-and-extension-in-bash)

Comment: this looks good  but we could enhance it by getting unique values

Comment: Sorry, totally forgot about the `sort`, I've added it!

Comment: do you know about  finding creation date of a file  in linux ? is it possible ?

Comment: Of course you can get the creation date. However, that's out-of-scope for your current question. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14842195/how-to-get-file-creation-date-time-in-bash-debian)

Answer (score 0):

Using this i solved it

```sh
find . -type f -name "[^.]*.*" -exec bash -c 'printf "%s\000" "${@##*.}"' argv0 '{}' + | sort -uz | tr '\0' '\n'
```